# useContext() is undefined in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';

const Context = React.createContext();
const Provider = ({children}) => {
   const color = "blue";
   return (<Context.Provider value={color}>{children}</Context.Provider>);
};

const useContext = () => {
   const context = React.useContext(Context);
   console.log(context); // undefined
}

export {useContext};
```

React.useContext(Context) returns `undefined` value.
If I try `const Context = React.createContext("")`, this returns `""`.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: you should read this i think : https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext

Comment: How do you use the `useContext` function you define?

Comment: Please show reproducible example [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can make your MRE **runnable** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). That helps people help you.

Comment: Did you use your Provider acutally? The default value is `undefined` since you did not pass any argument to `createContext`.

Comment: This is a small example that might help you [Link](https://daveceddia.com/usecontext-hook/)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to get access to your `value` prop in any child-component under your Provider

```
  export const useColorContext = () => React.useContext(Context);
```

Consume it like...

```
<Context.Provider value={color}>
  <ChildComponent>...</ChildComponent>
</Context.Provider>


function ChildComponent() {
  const currentColor = useColorContext();
  /** ... */
}
```

Comment: Spread hate? What? I commented on the error, after you fixed it I removed it and upvoted.

Answer (score -1):

```
const Context = React.createContext();
```

This will initiate the context. Initially the context value empty

And

```
React.useContext
```

It will call the value from the provider. So it should be child component of the provider. Otherwise it will be empty.

Then Don't redecalre with new function like `useContext` . Directly use `React.useContext` hook on component instead exporting